Pygame in django
I'm trying to make an online game using Django, but having some trouble:
Here is my game code in py/main.py
import pygame
import sys

def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((50, 50))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

    while True:
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

When I run server, it said "  no module name 'pygame'  "
After that, i tried to "py -m pip install pygame" but it said: already have
enter image description here
Then how can I import pygame in Django?
